# Foreach output into a file

Tags: tcl

Here is the code I tried

```
foreach_in_collection t1 [ ga ...] {
    set f1 [ga $t1 type_name]
    set f2 [ga $t1 bb]
    puts $f1
    puts $f2
    puts $file1 $f1 $f2
}
```

I want to write two output $f1 and $f2 to $file1, please let me know 
above puts $file1 [list $f1 $f2] also doesn't works..

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
set fd [open out.txt w]
foreach {x y} [list a b c d e] {
  puts x=$x
  puts y=$y
  puts $fd $x
  puts $fd $y
}
close $fd
```

**Output file (before):**

```
$ cat out.txt
cat: out.txt: No such file or directory
$
```

**Execution output:**

```
$ tclsh foo.tcl
x=a
y=b
x=c
y=d
x=e
y=
$
```

**Output file (after):**

```
$ cat out.txt
a
b
c
d
e

$
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharad's solution is perfect. There is one more way if you want to try.

SBORDOLO-M-V1VG:EXPERIMENT sbordolo$ cat a11

```
 exec rm -rf out1.txt ;# No need to worry about file is there or not.
 exec touch out1.txt
 exec chmod 777 out1.txt ;#You can give a write permission here. I have given 777 just like that

 foreach {x y} [list a b c d e f] {
   puts x=$x
   puts y=$y
   exec echo $x >> out1.txt 
   exec echo $y >> out1.txt 

 }
```

When you run the script:
SBORDOLO-M-V1VG:EXPERIMENT sbordolo$ tclsh a11

```
x=a
y=b
x=c
y=d
x=e
y=f
```

SBORDOLO-M-V1VG:EXPERIMENT sbordolo$ cat out1.txt

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```